# Direct select Layer (PS)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Since *some* of the newer cs versions of PS I got the problem that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd> stopped selecting layers directly when they're grouped in a folder. Instead PS simply selects the folder. If I <kbd>right click</kbd> inside the actual working space/viewport/image I get a somehow structured "tree" view with the folder name and the correct layer inside the folder. Is there a shortcut/mouse-keyboard click action that can directly select a layer inside the folder (again)?

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

The possible "solutions":

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd> = Select folder/group | Select outside a group
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd> = Select layer inside a folder group
- Mark "Auto select" (toolbar - top) + "Layer" from the drop-down
- <kbd>right click</kbd> then select the layer from the context menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using most of the tools (except `Move tool`):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd>

> If you can temporarily switch to move tool by pressing `cmd`, then this will work. For example if you are using the `Brush tool` this will work, but if you are using the `Crop tool`, this will not work.

**With move tool:**

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Left-click</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd>.

Left-click method and the right click method have one pretty interesting difference.

Left-click method does not select locked layers.
Right-click method selects locked layers.

---

Another difference with these two right-click methods, is that you can't move a layer while clicking, where as if you use the Left-click method, that may happen accidentally.

Comment: +1 - works. And yes, I always name my layers. Sadly PS always appends " - copy" to all layers when you copy a whole folder. A real pain if you are making nav menus for the web where you need multiple states (:hover, :active)...

Comment: Yea.. If possible I often stick hover and active state in the the same text layer in different menu items with different colors.

Comment: @Lorello I avoid doing it in the same layer, as this prevents using adjustments layers, fx, etc. So normally everything sits right beneath each other with offset. This way I can easily make sprites (overflow: hidden, etc.). Using only one img is imo better as it removes the need for several requests for only one image -> loads faster.

Comment: @kaiser Yeah.. I should really start being more organized.

Comment: Related question / answer: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18115/making-the-auto-select-layer-check-box-a-keyboard-hot-key/18119#18119

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a little work around.

Click your move tool and then in the topbar mark "auto-select" and set it to layer.
Now if you click inside the layer it will select it:

[image]

Once you have this checked you can also still use this if you have another tool (eg the select tool) active by simply CTRL+click it.

Comment: Sadly this makes no difference. I still can't select layers _inside a group/folder_ with your suggestion. [Ctrl] + *right click* is exactly the same.

Comment: auto select does make sens kaiser, though it select the layer only on which u click. restart your PS and do this again,sure something will happen...

Comment: i can select layers within groups, so it actually should work...

Answer (score 2):

Press "v" to select the "move" tool and be sure to select the option "layer" in the topbar menu.

Now your can `cmd` + `click` in some element and this will select its proper layer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows when you are in auto select and you have chosen Group in the Auto-select option drop down area.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + right-click on the object that you want to select on your canvas (the layer inside the group will be selected and not the entire group).  Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  While holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, left-click and drag the mouse.

You will notice the selected layer inside the group move and not the entire group itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this behavior. Try resetting preferences (hold down Cmd/Ctl, Opt/Alt and Shift while the program is launching) and see if that doesn't remedy the problem.

Comment: It's only about layers inside a folder (grouped layers). You can't directly select them (at least not in cs4 on win) with Ctrl+click

Comment: Perhaps there's something I'm not getting. I fired up CS4 specifically to check this. If I Ctl-click on an item that's inside a layer group, the group folder opens with that layer selected in the Layers panel. I don't have CS2 or CS3 installed right now, so I can't check that, but CS4, CS5 and CS5.1 all work exactly the same way.

Comment: Strange. Doesn't work for me (CS4). See update/edit i/t Q.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Channels tab. There might be a hidden mask there created by accident. This is what happened to me, I couldn't <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+CLICK anywhere.