# move tool in Photoshop CC version 19.1 vs Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In my company we just upgraded our Photoshop CS6, which I used for the last 6 years, to the newest Version of Photoshop CC.

I think it's quite the same, as a casual user that only does a bit of Webdesign and photo manipulation in it, I can't seem to find many differences

One difference however is driving me a bit crazy. In CS6 I could select a few layers, select the move tool and move all layers by left clicking inside my workspace and drag things around. When I do this in CC, everything gets deselected except the layer where my mouse lands on when I left click, and only this layer gets moved when I drag it around.

Same goes for folders which have a few layers in it. In CS6 I could select the folder layer and drag things around. now it also selects the layer in the folder I land on and only moves this one.

Can I somehow make CC behave like CS6 in this case, or do I have to adapt to the changes?

Comment: Damn... CS6 is already so much older than I thought. — You can temporarily enable auto select by holding down cmd or ctrl with the move tool active. [More about move tool layer select shortcuts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/18119/2332)

Comment: @Joonas we're old men, Joonas. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the top left of your main window with the Move Tool selected.

[image]

You can choose Auto-select by Layer, Group, or of course, Off.
It sounds like you're used to this being off, so it simply preserves whatever selection you already made in the Layers tab.

Comment: Great! exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Activating the **Move Tool** uncheck **Auto-Select** at the top options menu.

[image]